# UIButton in tvOS 9.1: focused state image not displayed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, focus, tvos9.1

I have 3 buttons (name Button A, Button B and Button C). In storyboard, I have added images for normal, focused and selected state.

Now suppose Button B is selected by default and its selected image is displayed.
Now by swiping, focus is provided to Button B.

Now in tvOS 9.0, focus state image for Button B is displayed.
But in tvOS 9.1, normal state image for Button B is displayed.

Can someone help, how to display focus state image for selected Button in tvOS 9.1